# Is it possible for ESLint to lint an html file where the script tag has the attribute type="text/worker"?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, eslint

I maintain a character sheet for Roll20.net and Roll20.net uses a custom script tag where type="text/worker". I'm using ESLint with Visual Studio Code. Is there a setting for ESLint to treat type="text/worker" as "text/JavaScript"? I reviewed the documentation for [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) but didn't find anything that would help.

All the html and code is saved to a single file, gurps.html.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<!-- html for character sheet -->
</div>

<script type="text/worker">

    var version = "2.1.2";

    var damageTable = [];

    // events and functions for character sheet.

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you set up the [eslint-plugin-html](https://github.com/BenoitZugmeyer/eslint-plugin-html) successfully, you can set the [`html/javascript-mime-types`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-html#htmljavascript-mime-types).

In your case adding the following to your `.eslintrc.json` will enable linting of `<script type="text/worker">` tags:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "eslint-plugin-html"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "html/javascript-mime-types": ["text/javascript", "text/worker"]
    }
}
```

After you have done that the [vscode-eslint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) extension will automatically respect that setting and lint the `<script type="text/worker">` tag's content.